# About a (new?) definition of transformation (anti.transformation) as a link between natural and dinatural transformations

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

This is not a hard topic, but I post here as "reference request" or because elementary  aspects (but not previously vocalized) can be interesting too for researchers.

Given $F: \mathscr{A}\to \mathscr{C}$, $G: \mathscr{A}\to \mathscr{C}^{op}$ I define a "anti-transformation"
$\alpha: F \Rightarrow^*  G$ as a family  of morphisms $\alpha_A: F(A) \to  G(A)$ for  $A \in  \mathscr{A} $ such that

$\alpha _A= G(f) \circ  \alpha _B\circ  F(f)$ for $f: A \to  B$ in $\mathscr{A}$

similarly if $F: \mathscr{A}\to \mathscr{C}^{op}$, $G: \mathscr{A}\to \mathscr{C}$.

Then the (vertical) composition of two anti-transformations $\alpha: F \Rightarrow^*  G$, $\beta : G \Rightarrow ^* H$ is a (usual) transformation, the composition of a anti-transformation by a transformation is a anti-transformation.
Moreover a dinatural transformation $\alpha : S \Rightarrow^: T: \mathscr{A} \times  \mathscr{A}^{op}\to \mathscr{C} $ is just a anti.transformation $S \Rightarrow^* (T^{op}\circ  tw)$ where $tw: \mathscr{A} \times  \mathscr{A}^{op} \to  \mathscr{A}^{op} \times  \mathscr{A}$ is the twisting functor.

***Is this known in literature?***

**Edit**: a anti.transformation $S \Rightarrow^* (T^{op}\circ  tw)$ is a dinatural tranformation, but no viceversa in general (consider the valutation $V\otimes V^*\to R$ about (real) vectorial (finite dimensional) spaces, where $V^*$ is the dual of $V$) .

Comment: What you call anti-transformation is just a functor $\mathscr A\rightarrow\operatorname{Fact}(\mathscr  C)$ to MacLane's twisted arrow category, a.k.a. Baues's category of factorisations $\operatorname{Fact}(\mathscr  C)$ of $\mathscr C$, http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+factorizations.